# not enough memory to perform requested operation-Android studio Out of memory issue

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-studio-3.0

I have been using Android Studio 3.0 for a while now, and in my previous version it seemed to work just fine. But now i get this error: how can i solve this ...

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRO9K.png)